# DataTypes in Linq query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, types

I already read about SQL-CLR Type Mapping but don't get it..... both shows me Int16 in console but when I try

```
f.smallId = dr[0];
```

even a simple test

```
Int16 test=dr[0];
```

doesn't work:
It says now that dr[0] is an object

```
NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("select id from database", conn);
NpgsqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(dr[0].GetType());
    foreach (Definitions f in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f.smallId.GetType());
        f.smallId = dr[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: dr[0] is a column in a DataRow and must be cast to an integer Int16 test = (Int16)dr[0];

Comment: thx that actually did it...is it considered even good programming practice,...anyway to directly read it from the table, since its already Int16, and a cast seems unnecessary

Comment: Yes.  The DataReader returns everything as an object and must be cast to the actual type.  There is no other way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because [`DbDataReader.Item` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsa8xa84%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  returns `object` and there is no implicit conversation from `object` to `Int16` but there *is* an explicit conversation.

Just use;

```
Int16 test = (Int16)dr[0];
```

Also use `using` statement to dispose your command and adapter automatically.

Comment: copy that Soner.....  what does it do? closes the reader and closes the connection?

Comment: @Tetragrammaton Yes, the `using` statement will take care of closing the reader and the connection. In your case, as Soner said, you have to use two separated `using` (one for your command and one for your reader).